# How can I define an element to be the same type as an element pointed at by a random access iterator?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, quicksort

I want to define v to be the same type as an element pointed at by RAIterator below.

```
template < class RAIterator , class Comparator >
  void g_quick_sort_3w_opt (RAIterator beg, RAIterator end, Comparator& cmp)
  {
    if ((end-beg) < 2)
        return;

    RAIterator low = beg;
    RAIterator hih = end;
    RAIterator i = beg;

    T v = *beg; //I want T to be the type of an element pointed at by RAIterator

    while (!(i == hih))
    {       
        if (cmp(*i , v)) Swap(*low++, *i++);
        else if (*i == v) ++i;
        else Swap(*i, *--hih);
    }
    g_quick_sort_3w_opt(beg, low, cmp);
    g_quick_sort_3w_opt(hih, end, cmp);
  }
```

Swap is the one from genalg.h

right now my test input is a list of integers, the above works if I use int instead of T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), especially the `reference` and `value_type` members.

```
typename std::iterator_traits<RAIterator>::value_type v = ...;
typename std::iterator_traits<RAIterator>::reference v = ...;
```

Of course, you might be well-served with just using automatic type-deduction:

```
auto v = ...; // Beware of proxies
```

Comment: Just a quick mention that `iterator_traits` is designed to handle raw pointers as well as standard iterators (and non-standard iterators that follow the standard conventions).

Answer (score 0):

`typename RAIterator::value_type v = *beg;`

Comment: Let's hope the iterator is a class-type, right? `T*` is a valid iterator-type.

Comment: @Deduplicator ... which I see you've already written about. I'll remove my rubbish.

Comment: @Deduplicator Scratch that. I'll leave it, as your comment makes a point that is worth leaving in plain sight.

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, you can use `auto`

```
auto v = *beg;
```